# Difference between assigning strings

Tags: c

In C I tried to assign a sting to variable in two different ways

```
char question[200];
strcpy( question, "This is the question" );
```

and

```
char question[] = "This is the question";
```

and both works...
but what's the difference between these two methods?

Comment: 1. `strcpy()` copy from destination to source. 2. `=` initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is probably flexibility. This

```
strcpy( question, "This is the question" );
```

you can do anytime after you declare the variable.
Whereas this:

```
char question[] = "This is the question";
```

You have to use directly during declaration time.

In the second
example the length of `question` got fixed to length
of text +1 for null terminator. You can't change
length of this variable later, so you can't assign larger
string to it for example.

Comment: One could also say that the strcpy version is _less_ flexible, since you are then limited to strings with less than 200 characters (199 plus '\0').

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: In that sense yes, although I meant from a different point of view :).

Comment: Just for the records, the C standard distinguishes declaration and definition. Here the important thing is that the second method is an *initialization* at the point of the definition of the variable.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in the first example, you allocate 200 sizes of "char" in memory. In second one, you allocate 21 of them.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
char question[200];
strcpy( question, "This is the question" );
len = sizeof(question);
```

`len = 200`

But in

```
char question[] = "This is the question";
len = sizeof(question);
```

`len = 21`

> Which means, in 1st case you can rewrite the string with atmost 199 chars which is not possible in 2nd case. It would lead to out of bounds access error.

Answer (score 0):

Both works but there are also other implications. Using fixed buffers can be dangerous especially with strcpy.

If you are copying a string longer than 200 bytes into your *question* buffer, you will overwrite other data on the stack, causing a **buffer overflow**.

Sometimes using dynamically allocated strings might be preferable, but then you would need to make sure you do not cause a memory leak (this is what higher level languages do behind the scenes, like c++ with std::string).